# Save Google Maps Marker to Firebase with AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers, ionic2, angularfire2

I'd love your help with saving a google maps marker to firebase with the AngularFire2 library. I'm a journalist working on an collaborative mapping app idea. I'm learning Angular 2 to make an Ionic 2 app. I've been stuck on this step for a while and am eagerly looking for some direction to move forward. I might have one or to things wrong, or I might be way off. But I'm having trouble with this conceptually. I've tried to emulate the AngularFire2 docs the best I can.

I'd like to pass the marker object to firebase when a user clicks the addMarker() button to drop a marker at their location. Eventually I want users to include a photo in the info window. But for now I need firebase to save the markers in the realtime database.

Here is my home.html file:

```
 <ion-header>
   <ion-navbar>
     <ion-title>Map</ion-title>
       <ion-buttons end>
         <button ion-button (click)="addMarker(marker.value)"><ion-icon name="add"> 
       </ion-icon>Add Marker</button>
      </ion-buttons>
     </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
     <div #map id="map"></div>
  </ion-content>
```

Here is a portion of my home.ts file:

...

```
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  map: any;
  mapInitialised: boolean = false;
  apiKey = 'I put my key here';

  constructor(public nav: NavController, public connectivityService: ConnectivityService, af: AngularFire ) {
this.items = af.database.list('/items');
```

...

```
addMarker(){
let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: this.map,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  position: this.map.getCenter()
  });

 let content = "<h4>Information!</h4>";

 this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);

 this.map.addListener('click', () => {
   this.items.push({ marker })
 });

 };
addInfoWindow(marker, content){

  let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: content
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
    infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
  });

}


}
```

Comment: I figured this out and will post the code soon.

Comment: Did you figure out how?